# Can anyone identify this track lighting fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I'm looking for more light fixtures like this one. Can anyone identify it?

[image: mystery fixture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a [Juno track light](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EVO3WA).

Answer (score 2):

It's a Progress Lighting Gimball ring track head.

Comment: It's also NOT a "strip lighting fixture", that's something else.

Comment: Yep it's a track light fixture.